# change tab name in Gitlab login page

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I included LDAP in my Gitlab-ee server and sucesfully changed one tab name to company name. But, for admin log in tab, it is shown as `standard`. I want to change to `Admin`. How it is done?

I saw in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitlabhq/d3orbQl9cJk) google group question but was unsucessful as the given link not opening for self hosted Gitlab.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open file `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/views/device/shared/_tabs_ldap.html.haml`
2. Search for word `Standard` and change it to `Admin`
3. Open terminal and `gitlab-ctrl restart`

Answer (score -1):

Edit **file** `app/views/devise/shared/_tabs_ldap.html.haml` directly on the server and restart the service with `gitlab-ctl restart`.

Comment: Where will be the `app` folder?